# Different combinations using different items

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I have balls of different colors:

- 1 red,
- 1 white,
- 5 oranges,
- 2 black,
- 0 green.

I want to make an algorithm, in Java, to count the maximum number of combinations of, exactly, 3 different colors.

For example, in this case, multiple solution are possible, but I look for the maximum number of combination. There is 2 in this example :

- (1 red, 1 orange, 1 black)
- (1 white, 1 orange, 1 black)

Can you suggest me a solution ? 
Thank you !!!

Comment: Paul : Because he already use them. This was an example, multiple solutions are possible, but two is the maximum number of combinations you can make on one time.

Comment: Try searching for "backtracking" using your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each stage just pick the 3 colours you have the most of.

For example, suppose you have 2 red, 3 green, 7 blue, 1 yellow and 4 white.

You should first pick blue, white and green because 7, 4 and 3 are the biggest numbers.

Then you have 2 red, 2 green, 6 blue, 1 yellow and 3 white.

6, 3 and 2 are the biggest numbers, so you should pick blue, white and red/green (it doesn't matter if you choose red or green).

Keep going in this way until you have less than 3 colours left and you'll find the maximum.

A formal proof that this algorithm works is surprisingly complicated, and it can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1729247/328863).

Comment: If we have 4 red, 3 green, 3 blue, 3 yellow and 3 white. Following this solution, I found 4 combinations, but It is possible to get 5 combinations. I think this solution doesn't work.

Comment: I just checked that case, you do get 5. 43333 -> 32233 -> 22222 -> 11122 -> 01111 -> 00001. I didn't prove it mathematically, but I'm reasonably sure it works.

Comment: @Mohamed2a The best place to ask is on MathExchange. Somebody will prove or disprove it in 5 minutes.

Comment: Okey @Paul, I see now, You are right !

Answer (score 0):

This brute-force solution algorithm (in java) does the work. It is slow but reliable :

```
    package combinations;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class Combinations {

        private static Map<String, Integer> balls = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        private static int maxCombinationsCount = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            // init
            balls.put("red",  1);
            balls.put("white", 1);
            balls.put("orange", 5);
            balls.put("black", 1);
            balls.put("green", 0);
            // begin calculation
            combine(0, 0);

            System.out.println(maxCombinationsCount);
        }

        public static void combine(int combinationCount, int combinationsCount)
        {
            for (String ball: balls.keySet()) {
                if (balls.get(ball) > 0) {
                    balls.replace(ball, balls.get(ball) - 1);
                    combinationCount ++;
                    if (combinationCount == 3) {
                        maxCombinationsCount = Math.max(maxCombinationsCount, combinationsCount + 1);
                        combine(0, combinationsCount + 1);
                    }
                    else {
                        combine(combinationCount, combinationsCount);
                    }
                    combinationCount --;
                    balls.replace(ball, balls.get(ball) + 1);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Mine was a bad idea : if you put 18 red, 12 white and 5 orange ... it is very very sloooooow. I should put myself a -1 :).